# Scope variable not visible within ng-click handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular and am trying to figure out what's wrong here. There is a controller defined like this:

```
(function(){
    function myController($scope, CommsFactory) {

        $scope.doSomething = function() {
            var x = $scope;  // <- Doesn't work because $scope is not defined
        }
    }

    angular
        .module('aModule')
        .controller('myController', myController);
})();
```

The doSomething() method is then called by a button click like:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="doSomething()" class="btn--link" value="do it"/>
```

This seems straightforward to me but the problem is that, when I break within the method, $scope is not defined. This is different from most of the examples I've seen, and I can't figure out why. Shouldn't it be visible here? Obviously a lot of code is missing - I've tried to show only the relevant bits - could I be missing something somewhere else?

Comment: in your code $scope.x is undefined indeed

Comment: I'll clarify: $scope itself is not visible. I was using that as an example. I'll edit to make more clear.

Comment: @Gadzooks34 Your line `var x = $scope;` looks kind of strange. What is your expected outcome of `doSomething()`?

Comment: I know, I know. It's a dummy line. The point is that $scope itself is not visible within doSomething(). My question is: why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: It turns out that what I was experiencing had something to do with the way in which the Chrome debugger works. It appears to do some kind of lazy loading of variables defined outside of the function in which you break (or at least this as far as I've characterized it). What this means, at least in my case, is that if I break inside of the method, and $scope isn't actually used within that method (which, unfortunately, I was doing a lot because I was trying to verify that $scope was visible), then the debugger will report that $scope is unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

You're **declaring a module** then you need to add **`[]`**.

Something like this:

```
angular.module('aModule', [])
        .controller('myController', myController);
```

> **Usage**
>
> `angular.module(name, [requires], [configFn]);`
>
> **Arguments**
>
> - **name.-** The name of the module to create or retrieve.
> - **requires (optional).-** If specified then new module is being created. If unspecified then the module is being retrieved for further
>     configuration.
> - **configFn (optional).-** Optional configuration function for the module. Same as Module#config().

Please, I would to recommend to read this guide about Angular Module:
[angular.module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

```js
(function() {

  function myController($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function() {
      var x = $scope;
      console.log(x);
    }
  }

  angular
    .module('aModule', [])
    .controller('myController', myController);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="aModule">
  <div data-ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="button" ng-click="doSomething()" class="btn--link" value="do it" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct about those brackets `[]`, but as Gadzooks just posted a snippet of his code, I'd assume that the module declaration happens in another file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is generally working fine as demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Loxos/hu8ckvz6/).

Your main problem seems to be in the usage of `$scope`. `$scope` is an object containing all variables and methods which should be available in the corresponding template. For this reason, you would always reference a member of $scope, instead of the whole object.
Furthermore, John Papas AngularJS style guide recommends the usage of `controllerAs` in favor of `$scope` for multiple reasons as stated in [Y030](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y030)

By convention, you should also give your controllers uppercase names and use explicit Dependency Injection

A typical use case would rather look like:

```
(function(){

    angular
        .module('aModule', [])
        .controller('myController', MyController);

    MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'CommsFactory'];

    function MyController($scope, CommsFactory) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.doSomething = doSomething;

        function doSomething() {
            var $scope.x = "Did it!";
        }
    }

})();
```